# Cube Root of Modulo N

Tags: c++, module, brute-force

c = a^3 MOD b

"c" and "b" are known. I need to calculate the "a". And b = 1 MOD 3, b = 4 MOD 9

"a" and "b" are in 128 bytes, "c" has almost same length. They (a, b, c, d) are not Prime.

Thanks,

Comment: Please add an example and things you have tried.

Comment: for example, b=134217728 and c=66444249 -> I want to find the "a" which should be 777. Actually, the numbers are big (128 bytes length).

Comment: I said that "b" is not a prime. I used the "bdcalc" to test it by function "isprime()". It says that "b" is not a prime. But, I have a doubt now :-( if "b" is a prime and b = 4 MOD 9 (in my case), the root can be calculated -> root = pow(a,(2*b + 1)/9, b). But, it is quite difficult to calculate it for 128 bytes length numbers. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to breaking RSA encryption with public exponent 3

Comment: This same person asked in the Mersenneforum and had it answered there as well

Comment: RSA encryption is in the form `c = m^e mod N` where `e` and `N` together form the public key, `c` is the ciphertext and `m` is the plaintext message. Solving this problem is indeed equivalent to breaking RSA security. The catch, however, is that RSA gets its security in the `mod N` part, where `N = p * q` (`N` is composed of two primes, being `p` and `q`). To solve this problem, `N` has to be factorized into these (private) primes `p` and `q`, which is a problem in NP. Thus, for a large N, factorization is infeasible and the problem cannot be solved in reasonable time.